# this code causes my game lag after several restarts of the level. any suggestions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lag

This code makes my game lag after several restarts of the level. but it works fine at the start of the game. Are there any suggestions?

```
void Update()
{
    float max = 1f;
    transform.position = new Vector3(3.22f + Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 2, max), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: How do you know this is what is causing the lag

Comment: I can guarantee you that this code is not the reason for your lag

Comment: @AliBaba i have tested the game using a profiler with and without this code and it worked fine and cpu usage was much lower without this script.

Comment: @Levan Why do you declare max at every update??

Comment: This 'could' be the cause of your lag, if you maybe have it running ~ 10k + times. Maybe you can post a bit more context in regards to the script that actually contains this update?

Comment: I suspect, that this script is running on many GameObjects and these objects are not destroyed, when you reload the level. There is no issue with the code itself.

Comment: @NikolaG. thanks, it helped i think xD

Comment: @AliBaba i use poolobjects.dispose to destroy it